# How to run selenium webdriver in the background?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've been using Selenium for 2 weeks.

It's been really useful so far.

When developing, I like having the browsers pop up so I can see what's going on, but in production, I don't want the server to keep opening and closing Firefox windows.  I've looked through this forum, done Google searches, etc., but can't find a way to run the browsers in the background.

Anybody have a tip on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try PhantomJS which is a headless browser webkit. **HTMLUnit** is also similar to PhantomJs; however, usage of PhamtomJs is highly recommended.

**PhantomJs** uses `Google chrome's JavaScript Engine` but without a GUI.

Refer :http://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 6):

Found simple solutin for JAVA Seleniun Google Chrome

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("headless");
    return new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Great, simple way.

Answer (score 2):

if the server is on linux, you can allocate a display just to run selenium using [Xvfb](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xvfb) to create a virtual display

if the server is on windows you can register the daemon to run as another user than the user logged in, giving the service a desktop. this only work for the local system admin account [or by registry tweaking as detailed here](http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/) note that you will have to set up internet explorer properties for the user the service is running as

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try : https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver.

It uses Headless approach to automate websites.

Answer (score 1):

Phantom is good headless option, but sssuming you want to stick with same tools you are using ... (the following assumes Linux as platform)

1. install xvfb (apt-get install xvfb)
2. You can then run selenium/firefox "headless" (assuming Linux) with the following command:-

DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run java -jar [selenium JAR filename]

Now, when your test suite kicks off selenium, it will run using Firefox without browser windows popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about running against a Selenium Grid instead? See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2