# Prevent browser window from coming to foreground

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I use an extension method to invoke interactions in a new browser tab:

```
    public static void DoInNewTab(this ChromeDriver driver, Action<ChromeDriver> action)
    {
        var currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        // DOES NOT WORK:
        //driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + "t");
        driver.ExecuteScript("window.open()"); // HERE
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
        action.Invoke(driver);
        driver.Close(); // HERE
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentHandle);
    }
```

Works like a charm, except that the browser window keeps getting activated and coming to the foreground and getting focus. It is a bit clumsy to debug, as breakpoints obviously activate the IDE window, but as far as I can see, the browser window gets activated on the lines marked with `HERE`.

How can I prevent the window from being activated and make sure it stays in the background?

Comment: If you want the browser run in background, this link can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26018790/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-in-the-background

Comment: @PhatHuynh Thanks for your idea! Unfortunately there are occasions where I need to interact with the window, so headless is not an option...

Comment: I really don't think you can. You can try with selenium grid https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp but this requires a remote vm where you will run the browsers.